# Get row count for all tables across dbs and pivot sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

I am using the following script to get a row count for all databases
These databases are all identical in structure.

```
USE [MyTestDb1];

SELECT 
    'MyTestDb1'as [Database Name], so.name AS [Table Name],   
    rows AS [RowCount]   
FROM 
    sysindexes AS si   
JOIN 
    sysobjects AS so on si.id = so.id   
WHERE 
    indid IN (0,1)   
    AND xtype = 'U'

USE [MyTestDb2];

SELECT 
   'MyTestDb2'as [Database Name], so.name AS [Table Name],   
    rows AS [RowCount]   
FROM 
    sysindexes AS si   
JOIN 
    sysobjects AS so on si.id = so.id   
WHERE 
    indid IN (0,1)  
    AND xtype = 'U'
```

At run time from c# I build the sql script depending how many dbs I am comparing and then execute.

Given that I want to compare the rows across many dbs on the same server
I cannot seem to achieve the following output.I believe is a pivot what I need 
but cannot seem to work it out.

```
TableName   Db1     Db2   Db3    Db4
------------------------------------
Table1      10      10    10     10
Table2      13      13    13     13
Table3      10      10    10     10
Table4      10      10    10     10
Table5      10      10    10     10
```

Any suggestion/help on how to return in the above format?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should use the more focused new `sys` catalog view: `sys.indexes`, `sys.tables` etc. - instead of the old, deprecated `sysobjects`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need `PIVOT` at this point.

First of all declare a variable to get column names dynamically

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Database Name] + ']', '[' + [Database Name] + ']')
               FROM    
               (
                    SELECT DISTINCT 'MyTestDb1'as [Database Name]   
                    FROM sysindexes AS si   
                        join sysobjects AS so on si.id = so.id   
                    WHERE indid IN (0,1)   
                    AND xtype = 'U'
                ) PV 
               ORDER BY [Database Name]
```

Now pivot the result as database names in columns and table names in rows.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '-- This outer query forms your pivoted result
             SELECT * FROM 
             (
                SELECT ''MyTestDb1'' as [Database Name], so.name AS [Table Name],   
                rows AS [RowCount]   
                FROM sysindexes AS si   
                    join sysobjects AS so on si.id = so.id   
                WHERE indid IN (0,1)   
                AND xtype = ''U''
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 --Defines the values in each dynamic columns
                 MIN([RowCount])
                 -- Get the names from the @cols variable to show as column
                 FOR [Database Name] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p            
            ORDER BY [Table Name];' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

**EDIT :**

I have inserted the data to temporary table for the easy understanding. `CTE1` converts csv to rows, `CTE2` gets the data from `sys....`. In the last part, we use `CROSS JOIN` as there is no need of a `INNER JOIN` as per your requirement.

```
DECLARE @PARAM VARCHAR(MAX)='DB1 | DB2 | DB3'

;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Database Name' 
    FROM  
    (         
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@PARAM, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data              
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT so.name AS [Table Name],   
        rows AS [RowCount]   
    FROM sysindexes AS si   
        join sysobjects AS so on si.id = so.id   
    WHERE indid IN (0,1)   
    AND xtype = 'U'
)
SELECT [Database Name],[Table Name],[RowCount]
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE1 
CROSS JOIN CTE2
```

Now declare the variable to get columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) 
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'DatabaseName' 
                FROM  
                (         
                     SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@PARAM, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data              
                ) AS A 
                CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
            ) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT [Database Name],[Table Name],[RowCount]
    FROM #NEWTABLE  
)TAB
PIVOT 
(
     MIN([RowCount])
     for [Database Name] in (' + @cols + ')
) as P' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your brilliant quick reply.Still digesting it, however how do I modify it to add more dbs to it.Could you show it with 2 dbs as an example.thanks

Comment: You need to list all db's with corresponding table names and its row count? @developer9969

Comment: sorry for being silly here and I appreciate your help,but i dont get where I add "db1,db2 etc.  
AND xtype = ''U''' from sys.databases  WHERE name in('db1','db2')

Comment: Did  u get the result? @developer9969

Comment: Are you passing db names as parameters? Or you are selecting all the db's and all tables? @developer9969

Comment: dbnames as parameters

Comment: So for each parameters, you will be executing stored procedure each time .Right? And finally you want report  that all db's. Right ? @developer9969

Comment: What I will do is I will pass a delimited string of dbs 'Db1|db2|db3|' etc.. convert that delimited string to a table with one column DbName and then i have a table with all the dbs i need to report. For semplicity if you find it easier hardcode the names of the db and I can always have it as a sql script and replace the names in c# before executing it

Comment: So, what do u expect me to do for u? @developer9969

Comment: If you could help me output the result as for multiple dbs as a pivot in the simplest way you find that would be great.Hardcoding at least 2 dbs in your sample would be fine. Dont worry about params if too time consuming.I dont want to abuse your help.

Comment: I just need to know one more thing. Does all the db have the same number of tables, with same table name and same row count? @developer9969

Comment: All the dbs will have the same tablenames and number of tables but rowcount for the each table might differ. that is the all purpose of the query.

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR EFFORT.I have learnt few things today from you